# sync a folder to google drive without making another copy of it on computer?

Tags: windows-7, sync, google-drive

I have around 50 gig of music residing on my non-windows partition which I want to sync to google drive but there's not enough space on my windows drive. I do not wish to move my music or make another copy of 50 gig data just for syncing. How can I sync my music without taking up any space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a [directory junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) should work here. Open command prompt (win+r -> type cmd) and browse to the google drive folder (see [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100525013119AAAbAWO) to see how). Then enter this command to make a junction to your music folder

```
mklink /j Music "d:/folders/Music".
```

Change the folders names as you need.

This will make google drive app think that the "Music" shortcut you just made is an actual directory that resides in the drive folder . Sync should work seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am the only one experiencing this, but folders linked by junctions sync only once! Building upon the answer above, I have a script that periodically deletes the junction, and creates it again (with a 5 second delay in between, so that Google Drive catches the delete).

```
rmdir Documents
timeout 5
mklink /J "Documents" "C:\Users\SuperUser\Documents"
```

This will only reupload new files, but it will process/scan all files in the directory. Downside is that it doesn't catch deleted files... Best workaround might be to just move the directory to Google Drive and create a link from the old location to the new one.

Comment: No, junctions are visible to apps just like real folders. They sync just like normal folders.

Comment: Can you confirm that folders synced to Google Drive via junctions continue working after the initial sync? For example, after the initial sync you place a new file in the junctioned folder and it will be uploaded? It does not work for me...

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I keep my 65GB google drive space in external HDD using a junction. Even though external HDD is connected only half the time, I never faced any problems.

Comment: Maybe disconnecting and reconnecting the drive is what triggers sync. Do you have selective sync or did you chose to sync the whole drive? Btw, doesn't google drive delete your files from cloud when you disconnect the drive?

Comment: No problems whatsoever. I have selective sync enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Drive doesn't sync changes in junctions and often doesn't see deleted junctions, so I sync with this script:

```
Taskkill /IM googledrivesync.exe /F
timeout 10 /nobreak

set NOTES="c:\Users\name\Google_Drive\stuff\my_notes"
fsutil reparsepoint delete %NOTES%
rmdir %NOTES%

set PROJECT_1="c:\Users\name\Google_Drive\stuff\my_project"
fsutil reparsepoint delete %PROJECT_1%
rmdir %PROJECT_1%
rem   -- add your junctions here (3 lines by every junction) --

start "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe"
timeout 60 /nobreak
mklink /J %NOTES% "c:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes"
mklink /J %PROJECT_1% "c:\Users\name\projects\project1"
rem   -- add your junctions here (1 line by every junction) --
```

just change paths and add your folders-junctions if needed!